# Query a Required field Prop()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to query:

```
var x = $("#fieldname").prop("required") === true;
```

What I am trying to achive is If required = true and the field is EMPTY do blah blah.   The Main issue I am having is how to add the EMPTY field to the query with out adding another IF statement

Comment: Why the `=== true` test? If you need a boolean-ish value, the result of `prop` should be sufficient.

Comment: Do you just want `if ($('#fieldname').prop('required') && !$('#fieldname').val())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to execute code based on the required property being present or not, the pattern is basically:

```
if ($("#fieldname").prop("required")) {
  // Is required.
} else {
  // Is not required.
}
```

You don't need to capture this into a variable, and you don't need to do a literal comparison to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($("#fieldname").prop("required") && !$('#fieldname').val()) {
// required and empty.
} else {
// not empty.
}
```

Comment: Would probably be a good idea to store `$('#fieldname')` in a variable to avoid duplicate DOM queries

Comment: forgive me I am a novice. I know how to store  data in a variable in php. I suspect it is similar, please show me an example  based on $('#fieldname') thanks